# ADC forwarding directly to UART

Tags: microcontroller, adc, uart, texas-instruments

I have an TM4C123GH6PM, I have also the board EK-TM4C123GXL with that MCU. I am new to microprocessors and still studying to learn. I have to implement a project with a Bluetooth module, which connects over UART to a host MCU. I want to know if I can use this MCU for the host.

The MCU will read an analog signal, and must sample continuously and periodically with a rate of at least 8000-10000 samples per second. In real time, this data will be forwarded directly to the UART and sent to the Bluetooth module. My questions are,

- First of all, is this possible with this MCU?
- Secondly, I know how to use UART and how to use ADC basically, but
  how do I configure ADC to run periodically and continuously - if that
  is not the default- ?
- Thirdly, as I know, the UART operates with 10 bits when there is only
  one stop bit and no parity bit, the remaining is 8 bits, how do I
  workaround to get 12 bits of data per sample from ADC, other than
  truncating?

Comment: Should be fast enough - but it really depends on your Bluetooth module, the common HC-05 can be programmed to go up to 1382400 baud (which is greater than 100Kbytes/s)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to sample at a regular interval with as little jitter as possible so setup your MCU program to operate with a timer interrupt at your needed sample rate. Then at each interrupt read the results of the previous conversion and trigger the next conversion. Some MCUs have built in hardware than can be configured to trigger A/D conversions from a timer overflow.

From the questions you have asked above it seems that you will need to do some investigation into your particular MCU to figure out how to use the timers and interrupts.

UARTs are good for 8-bit data bytes. The way you transmit 12-bits from an A/D converter is one of several ways.

a) Send first 8-bits of the sample in one UART byte followed by 4-bits in the next UART byte.

b) Send the first 6-bits in a UART byte followed by the remaining 6-bits in the next UART byte.

c) Both above approaches waste UART bandwidth on bit times not transmitting useful data so another scheme is to send two samples of the A/D (2 x 12 bits) packed into three UART bytes (3 x 8 bits). The packing can be sliced many ways but one common method used is to send the following sequence [Sample1(7:0)] [Sample2(7:0)] [Sample1(11:8)Sample2(11:8)].

Comment: One advantage of method "b" above, is that each byte has two un-used bits, one of which could be used as an identifier to indicate which byte comes first. Without this, you would probably have to rely on timing to determine which comes first, and this timing could be difficult when passing data through Bluetooth or if passing to a device where communications timing is not so deterministic such as a PC.

Comment: @Tut - Indeed framing is very important in any scheme like this. The 6/6 bit splits do permit framing marking to be added to the stream. I wonder if the OP is ready for that yet?

Comment: So, doing that for approximately 8000 - 10000 times/sec, for 16000 - 20000 UART packages/sec, is fine for this 80 MHz MCU?

Comment: @natsirun - You will have to evaluate your system requirements to determine the answer to your secondary question here. You'll need to see if the MCU and BlueTooth module can take baud rates at 10x the number of UART bytes per second. Another very important consideration is if the BlueTooth module has the capability and horsepower to receive the bytes at the high rate and still be able to utilize them for the BlueTooth channel. This is called "system design" and requires way more work than a question in EE StkXchg of "will it work".

Comment: I have Bluegiga WT12, the datasheet says it has a 3.0Mbaud rate at max, so I don't think I have problems in that. I am asking, if I can run this MCU that fast?

Comment: @natsirun - It's still "system design". Read your data sheets and get familiar with your parts. From that study you should be able to determine if the MCU can handle the raw UART baud rates. It will then be up to the design of the firmware you put on the part as to whether it can sustain keeping the UART fed at the rates required.

Comment: "Send the first 6-bits in a UART byte followed by the remaining 6-bits in the next UART byte. " That's nonsense, don't do that.

Comment: @Lundin - I think you should qualify your criticism rather than just trashing. Do note comments regarding framing synchronization bits which are possible in a [6][6] split or a [7][5] split but not feasible with a [8][4] split. If the data transmissions were wrapped as data payload into a higher level packet protocol then any type of data splitting/packing can be used as chosen for the system design. But there are times when using an async channel like a UART that the data bandwidth requirements leave little choice but to send raw data with minimal framing.

Comment: Well, sync bits are pretty much as stone age as UART technology itself... The bottleneck in this system is clearly the bluetooth module - all such modules on the market have non-existent real-time performance (we're talking lots of ms in lag and no specified response time), so it doesn't make sense to go chase bits in the UART protocol. My point is that you'll get the output from the ADC as a whole number and so it makes sense to transmit it that way. Little endian or big endian, the latter being most common and standard for network endianess.

Comment: @Lundin - Have you used a UART channel for data transmission? How do you propose to send a 12-bit ADC value through that channel as a "whole number" when the channel sends things in 8-bit or 7-bit (depending upon UART configuration) chunks?

Comment: By splitting it in 2 bytes as per your specified endianess, as I already mentioned. Do you know what endianess means?

Comment: @Lundin - Being in the computer and software world since 1970 you can be assured I know what endianness means. But we come full circle here when you now admit that the ADC samples have to be split into two bytes to be sent when you started out saying to not do that. If your argument is that that should be done with an [8][4] split then that falls flat on its face in a raw transmission channel because there is not a reliable way to encode framing into the data flow. So thus we are right back to why [6][6] or [7][5] splits are used ... with endianness issues not being any part of this.

Comment: @Lundin - Further discussion here is fruitless as the original question has been answered. Many practical production examples in my own experience have had to do just the type of things stated in my answer. Just because you think the UART is stoneage does not mean that folks find usage models for it and encounter issues like the OP here.

Comment: All I said was don't use your method b) because it adds nothing but obfuscation. Indeed there is no reliable way to encode framing in UART. Indeed the technology in itself falls flat on its face. Framing bits, sync bytes, parity and other forms of stone age tricks don't add much if you actually do the probability theory math for single bit/double bit/burst errors. You need to use a proper CRC to achieve anything like real data integrity. A simple CRC-8 is astronomically better than "framing tricks".